# How to set range for limit clause in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to set range for limit clause in hive , I have tried the below query but failed with syntax error . Can someone please help

```
select * from table limit 1000,2000;
```

Comment: Could you provide more details around your use case or desired results?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you should mark an accepted answer on this question. Judging by your history you may not know that it is customary to accept the answer that is of most help to you (and others). Please mark an accepted answer by clicking the outlined checkmark below the up/down vote buttons. Also it is typical to upvote the accepted answer as it must be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Row_Number** window function and set the range limit.

Below Query will result only the **first 20 records** from the table

```
   hive> select * from 
        (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by id) as rowid FROM <tab_name>
        )t 
    where rowid > 0 and rowid <=20;
```

Using **Between** operator to specify range

```
 hive> select * from 
            (
            SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by id) as rowid FROM <tab_name>
            )t 
        where rowid between 0 and 20;
```

To fetch rows from **20 to 40** then increase the lower/upper bound values

```
  hive> select * from 
            (
            SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by id) as rowid FROM <tab_name>
            )t 
        where rowid > 20 and rowid <=40;
```

Answer (score 4):

The LIMIT clause is used to set a ceiling on the number of rows in the result set. You are getting a syntax error because of an incorrect usage of this HQL clause.

The query could be written as the following to return no more than 2000 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2000;
```

You could also write it like so to return no more than 1000 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000;
```

However you cannot combine both into the same argument for LIMIT. The LIMIT argument must evaluate to a constant value.

I will try and expand on this information a bit to try and help solve your problem. If you are attempting to "paginate" your results the following may be of use.

FIRST I would recommend against leaning on HQL for pagination, in most situations that would be more efficiently implemented on the application logic side (query large result set, cache what you need, paginate with application logic). If you have no choice but to pull out ranges of rows you can get the desired effect through a combination of the LIMIT, ORDER BY, and OFFSET clauses.

LIMIT : This will limit your result set to a maximum number of row

ORDER BY: This will sort/order your result set based on one or more columns

OFFSET: This will start your result set at a certain row after the logical first entry in the table.

You may combine these three clauses to effectively query "pages" of your table. For example the following three queries show how to get the first 3 blocks of data from a table where each block contains 1000 rows and the target table's 'column1' is used to determine logical order.

```
SELECT title as "Page 1", column1, column2, ... FROM table
  ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
SELECT title as "Page 2", column1, column2, ... FROM table
  ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000;
SELECT title as "Page 3", column1, column2, ... FROM table
  ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000;
```

Each query declares 'column1' as the sorting value with ORDER BY. The queries will return no more than 1000 rows due to the LIMIT clause. Each result set will start at a different row due to the OFFSET being incremented by the "page size" for each query.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but ...

That will return the 1001 and the 2001 record in the query results set only if you are using hive a hive version greater than 2.0.0

```
hive --version
```

(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11531)

Answer (score 0):

`Limit` in Hive gives 'n' number of records randomly. It's not to print a range of records.
You may use `order by` in conjunction with limit to get what you want